# Does git pull change modified time of unaltered files?

Tags: git

I have a build step that takes a working copy, does some processing on it, and delivers it to our production server. The working copy is created using a hook from a bare repository that changes get pushed to. In order to reduce the time of the build step, it compares the modified time of files with the end time of the last build step, and only does extra processing (minification, cdn uplaod etc) if the file has changed. It seems that the build step is processing a lot more files than it should. My main suspect right now, is git.

When the git pull happens in the web hook, will unaltered files have their last modified time changed? If so, is there any work around?

Comment: git pull will change the time of files that have been modified on the remote repo. Why do you want to change the time of those files ?

Comment: @Nayur, I'm not wanting to change the time. I'm wanting to make sure that unaltered files don't get their mod time changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply tested it and no, `git pull` will not change the mtime of unchanged files.  The behavior you described would severely impair any Makefile centric build process.  Linux kernel developers wouldn't stand for it.

[Git does not store mtimes, for the reasons given in this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-and-mtime-td1518843.html), so once a file has been touched Git can't restore its mtime.  If you do a `git checkout`, any files which had to be changed to make your working copy match the checked out commit will be touched.

Your web hook may be doing something extra, like a checkout.